# Continuation to: How can I programmatically create a ListView full of strings containing columns and rows in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

As the title says I have based my work on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287051/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-listview-full-of-strings-containing-columns)
And that works! The problem is that I can't get to solve those problems:

1. Description column not wide enough (can't get to set it to the whole space with the star keyword
2. Items large enough to fit only one on line
3. Header colour not white
   [image]

The listviewCode is:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvPPtab1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}"  BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10,12.2,10,8.4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4"/>
    </ListView.Effect>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="250" Background="{x:Null}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

and it can be both  programmatically filled with items (real listview like) or with grids (datagrid like). In this case I am focusing on the datagrid like case.

```
ObservableCollection<String> obc = new ObservableCollection<string>();
obc.Add("AAAA");
obc.Add("BBB");

GridView myGridView = new GridView();
myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
//gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("ColumnOneHeader");
gvc.Header = Languages.Word(eWords.Description);
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc);

lvPPtab1.View = myGridView;
lvPPtab1.Items.Add("AAAA");
lvPPtab1.Items.Add("BBB");

lvPPtab1.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
lvPPtab1.Foreground = Brushes.Gainsboro;
```

What I have to simulate is something like what happens in explorer when you display images or names

[image]

Comment: Do it in XAML, not codebehind.

Comment: How? And why couldn't I do it programmatically

Comment: If your current approach is working for you, by all means stick with it.